# LUIS Test and Train takes more Time ( some times not completing it )

Tags: azure-language-understanding

i have created some Intent & Entities and would like to Train and Test the LUIS, but it is taking more time than usual, even sometimes it updates me with the error without completing the training. Is there any other alternative to train the Luis?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can train and test (and do much more...) LUIS using the [API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f). However, you cannot be sure that this will improve the performance. All if this is new and sometimes work not as good as the users expect.